# after dpkg-reconfigure console-setup not able to login on console keyboard

Tags: keyboard, login, console

I've freshly installed Ubuntu 18 server edition. 
There's is keyboard connected on USB, every thing worked ok.

I wanted to increase the default console fontsize with dpkg-reconfigure console-setup. This worked.
But after a reboot every time I tried to login from the console after entering the username about 4 or more extra enters / linefeeds are automatically generated so i cannot enter a password.
With ssh from another computer I can login to the server, but not thru the console.

Any help pointing me in the right direction to solve this is appreciated.

What I already have tried:
apt update
apt upgrade
several attempts with dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
changing keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

upgrading to kernel 4.20 solved the problem.

I followed theses instruction:
https://linuxhint.com/upgrade-kernel-ubuntu-1804/